# How to integrate a Zebra Scanner(2D way Imager) using Mobile(T53/T58) in react native

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner, scanning, zebra-scanners, zebra

I am using the React Native app version - 0.71.11. I have an existing app that has the function of the camera for barcode scanning, but we want to integrate a zebra scanner(2D way Imager) into this app. So, that I can use Zebra phone(t53/t58) to scan any barcode using its internal scanner.

Can anyone please share any thoughts?